# Pet system breaks when changing the name of currency

Tags: lua, roblox

So I have this code that is for a pet system in a game, the first started with "coins" as the currency but was changed to "taps" upon changing to "taps" the pet system partially broke. When it was "coins" it worked perfectly. Could someone help me fix it because it displays no errors.

```lua
local PetMultipliersModule = {}

--// Services
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local ServerStorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")

--// Variables
local DataFolder = ServerStorage.Data
local GameClient = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("GameClient")

--// Modules
local DataController = require(DataFolder.DataController)
local PetStats = require(GameClient.Modules.Utilities.PetStats)

--// Stat Variables
local Craft_Multipliers = {
    Normal = 1;
    Gold = 2;
    Shiny = 3;
}

--// Get Pet Stats
function GetPetStats(name)
    if PetStats[tostring(name)] == nil then
        warn("No Pet Stats for pet with name of", tostring(name))
        return PetStats.Dog
    end
    return PetStats[tostring(name)]
end

--// Get Individual Pet Multiplier
function GetPetMultiplier(Stats, PetLevel, PetEvolution)
    local tapMul, gemsMul = Stats.TapsMultiplier, Stats.GemsMultiplier
    local mul = Craft_Multipliers[tostring(PetEvolution)]
    if mul == nil then
        warn("No Craft Multiplier For ".. tostring(PetEvolution).." Evolution!")
        mul = 1
    end
    local petLevelMul = (tonumber(PetLevel) * 0.1) + 1
    if tonumber(petLevelMul) < 1 then petLevelMul = 1 end
    tapMul = tapMul * tonumber(petLevelMul) * tonumber(mul)
    gemsMul = gemsMul * tonumber(petLevelMul) * tonumber(mul)
    if tonumber(tapMul) < 1 then tapMul = 1 end
    if tonumber(gemsMul) < 1 then gemsMul = 1 end
    return tapMul, gemsMul
end

--// Get Pet Multipliers
function PetMultipliersModule:GetPetMultipliers(Player, Stat)
    if Player and Stat ~= nil then
        local tap, gems = 0, 0
        local Data = DataController:GetAllData(Player)
        local pets = Data.OwnedItems.Pets
        for _, v in pairs(pets) do
            if type(v) == "table" then
                local petName, evolution, PetLevel = v.PetName, v.PetEvolution, v.PetLevel
                if v.PetIsEquip == true and petName ~= nil and evolution ~= nil and PetLevel ~= nil then
                    local stats = GetPetStats(petName)
                    local tapMul, gemsMul = GetPetMultiplier(stats, PetLevel, evolution)
                    tap = tap + tonumber(tapMul)
                    gems = gems + tonumber(gemsMul)
                end
            end
        end

        if Stat == "Taps" or Stat == "Tap" then
            if tonumber(tap) < 1 then return 1 end
            return tonumber(tap)
        elseif Stat == "Gems" or Stat == "Gem" then
            if tonumber(gems) < 1 then return 1 end
            return tonumber(gems)
        elseif Stat == "Both" or Stat == "All" then
            if tonumber(tap) < 1 then tap = 1 end
            if tonumber(gems) < 1 then gems = 1 end
            return tonumber(tap), tonumber(gems)
        end
    end

    return 1, 1
end

return PetMultipliersModule
```

Me and my friend have asked the others devs that are working on the game and no fix was found also the only time when the code works is when we turn the currency to "coins"